# Count exclude max an min occurances

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

For eg. if we go to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_count):

And put

```
SELECT City, count(City) as Occurrences
FROM Customers 
GROUP by City
ORDER BY count(City) DESC
```

[image]

But what I really want is to exclude max and min occurances (ignore hard-coded 6 and 1 values for max and min), like

```
SELECT City, count(City) as Occurances
FROM Customers 
GROUP by City
HAVING count(City) != 6 AND count(City) != 1
ORDER BY count(City) DESC
```

[image]

What would be the way to get desired output without hard-coding 6 and 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT City, count(City) as Occurences FROM Customers,
(SELECT MAX(Occur) AS Ma,MIN(Occur) AS Mi FROM (SELECT City, count(City) as Occur
FROM Customers GROUP by City)) as T 
GROUP BY City HAVING Occurences!=T.Ma AND Occurences!=T.Mi ORDER BY Occurences DESC
```

Comment: Thanks!This is the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try with this

```
select c1.city, c1.cnt from (
select city, count(*) cnt from customers c
group by city
) c1 inner join 
(select max(cnt) max_cnt, min(cnt) min_Cnt from (
select city, count(*) cnt from customers c
group by city
)) c2
on c1.cnt!=c2.max_cnt and c1.cnt!=c2.min_cnt
;
```

as MySQL doesn't have an OVER..PARTITION BY function, which could maybe be useful.
Another approach could be on rownums and ordering but I prefer this